# ReactRouter - props from handlers to header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying out React Router. Simplified example to explain my question (at the bottom of the post):

**View1**

```
var View1 = React.createClass({
  statics: {
     headerAction: function() {
        this.handleSomething();
     }
  },

  handleSomething: function() {
     this.setState(...);
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        (...)
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Similar class for View2

**App**

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <AppHeader />

        <RouteHandler/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

**Router**

```
var routes = (
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
    <Route name="view2" handler={View2}/>
    <DefaultRoute handler={View1}/>
  </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

I want AppHeader to be in the App-class (not in the individual views), because the header/toolbar is always visible. If it where a part of the view class, the header would be re-mounted every time the router opened a different view. However, the props for that component can be different based on what route is active. Like a different title, and an icon with a clickable action causing something (state change) in the view.

I have tried to find out a good way to solve this, meaning different props for the AppHeader based on what view class is the active route handler. Since the view class is the component that varies, I thought about having it in the view components (View1/View2 in the example above) even if the props is not going to be used in that component. I have looked at having it as statics in theese component, then extracting them in Router.run, the problem with that is I cannot call event handlers in the same component (like in the View1 example), like clickable links for the header that is to do something in the view.

I tried to have a reflux store, and in componentWillUpdate of the view component, call some action on the store, that is listened to in the app component and sent as props to the header. However, for the first render, that action is called during the render process of the app component, causing the first header props not to be visible because they are not available yet.

Another approach I thought about was having one Reflux store per view (per router handler), and have the props for the header in the individual stores and pass them to the header in the App component. But then I need to switch between the stores to use, based on what route is active. I have not found any way to have individual stores per handler in addition to selecting the store with React Router.

What other option is there for a case like this?

Comment: Have you looked at the State mixin? this should allow you to view active routes. You could then grab the last one and do some manipulation in the App and pass it as props to the AppHeader. http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#State.

Comment: Are you still working on this? I have another idea that could be relevant.

Comment: I didnt go for RR on that project. But I've had similar case in other projects, so a good solution is always interresting.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but I solved a similar problem using `<Link>` from `react-router`.

```
render(){
  let to_obj={pathname:category.url, query:{text:category.text}}
  <Link to={to_obj} className="cat-link">
  .....
```

Then at the destination, I update the navbar title via a ReactiveVar with

`GlobalState.title.set(this.props.location.query.text)`

I haven't tried it but you may even be able to pass function/handlers down.

Just a thought.